# Time+ (CPU Time) column in top command is incorrectly reporting

Tags: linux, php, bash, redhat

The Time+ column in my top command is not reporting the correct time for a running php script.  It fluctuates up and down first reporting something like

```
TIME+
22:39.35 php
```

And then three seconds later reporting

```
TIME+
7:12.41 php
```

And then another three seconds later reporting

```
TIME+
42:44.21 php
```

Any clues as to why this is occurring?

**Edit:**

I hit "c" to toggle the name of the process so I know it's the same process.  The time is still being reported incorrectly.

Comment: You're 100% sure you were looking at the same process ID each time?

Comment: Yes, it seems like it's something out of the twilight zone.  However this time fluctuation only occurs with this particular script, all the others are correctly reported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you certain these are the same php processes? I bet you have multiple php processes that are "jumping on top".

If you want to better and easily monitor all php processes, I recommend using 'htop' much easier for what you are looking at.

Comment: Yah I hit "C" to toggle the name of the process...

Answer (score 2):

By default `top` sorts by %CPU, so you're going to see the process in the list move around. Use the `<` key repeatedly to move the sort column over to PID and the list will stop "jumping around" (at least, as long as new processes aren't stopping or starting). Alternatively, do a `ps p PID u` (substituting in the PID of the `php` process of interest) to see just that process in a `ps` listing. If the time isn't "jumping around" there then you're likely seeing an artifact of sorting in `top`.

Answer (score 1):

That value is calculated by taking the 14th field from /proc//stat which the kernel manages.

The value in question -- as far as I understand it -- only ever increases in 'jiffies' (effectively 100ths of a second).

Can you cat the value of /proc//stat for that pid ten seconds after one another?